# Nginx TCP proxy with load balancer

Tags: nginx, tcp, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I tried to create nginx tcp proxy for patroni (postgresql) databases.

**15432** - postgresql

**8008** - patroni, **HTTP 200** if ok, all other - errors

For work i use ngx_stream_core_module and ngx_stream_upstream_check_module.
For every node i create

```
stream {
...
  upstream db {
    server 127.0.0.1:15432;
    check interval=3000 rise=2 fall=5 timeout=1000 port=8008 type=http;
    check_http_send "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
    check_http_expect_alive http_2xx http_3xx;
  }
  server {
    listen 15434;
    proxy_bind 127.0.0.1;
    proxy_connect_timeout 4s;
    proxy_timeout 100s;
    proxy_pass db;
    #return 444;
  }
 ...
}
```

cluster config

```
  upstream db_cluster {
    server 192.168.8.201:15434 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
    server 192.168.8.202:15434 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
  }
  server {
    listen 5432;
    proxy_connect_timeout 100s;
    proxy_timeout 100s;
    proxy_pass db_cluster;
  }
```

But when all upstreams are died i need to return tcp refuse (or somethink another)?